# Screen rotation possible on Progressive Web App but not on Native android app

Tags: android, native, fullscreen, screen-orientation

I am building an app with Goodbarber, an app builder that allows users with no IT development skills like me to build native apps.
I am contacting you because I have a problem with my native Android application:

Screen rotation is not possible as soon as I'm on the native app. This is a problem for me because I would like to allow my users to put the youtube videos present in the application in full screen. I think the fact that the rotation is not possible, it blocks the full screen of youtube videos (the full screen icon is not clickable)

When I test the app in Progressive Web App, no problem. I can put its videos in full screen (the full screen icon is clickable and the full screen is displayed in 16-9).

I have already tested several codes such as for example:

- put a  in the  to change the orientation of the screen (without success)
- put '' allowfullscreen '' in the  (without success, even with allowfullscreen = "allowfullscreen")

Would you have a solution for me as I can't find any code that helps me?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some [parameters](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen) to test, I think you don't need "`allowfullscreen`" or stuff like that, rather `orientation` definitions:

Go into your `AndroidManifest.xml` and change `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` or that one you want from the parameter list.

For further fullscreen option take a look at this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive).

Good luck buddy! :)

Comment: Hey frirend,

Thank your help but my problem is that i don't have a AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: You should, do you use Android Studio or IntelliJ?

Comment: I developed the application mainly with html pages and some scripts i haven't created because i have not the skills ^^.

Comment: No i use Goodbarber it's a french app builder but for no skill guys like me XD

Comment: Oh then it^s obvious why it doesn't work. It's an "No-Code Mobile App builder", really limited as it implies. For further projects I suggest to learn java with Android Studio. Sorry I can't help you there, cuz its not possible in the app feature. But my answer would be correct for Android studio. So probably it can help other, if you tick it as answered. Sorry that I have no better news for you. But app builder aren't that flexible. Therefore Android Studio exists. Cheers :)

Comment: Yeah well that's the issue...
I will ask the support team from goodbarber to see if i can access this androidmanifest.xml file.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your support and your quick answers.
I will try to learn a lot more about java scripts and other....

Comment: Yes, you are welcome! Mark the answer as correct, it can help others, If you want to. I faced that issue too, years ago. :)